# Error: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x603000000070 overflowed to 0x60300000006c (stl_vector.h) (C++)

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have been trying to solve the sorted Squares leetcode problem (https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/fun-with-arrays/521/introduction/3240/), and I am mostly through it. However, I get the above error. Following is my code

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> sortedSquares(vector<int>& nums) {
        
        int start = 0;
        int end = nums.size()-1;
        vector<int> final(nums.size());
        int finalIdx = final.size()-1;
        int sqr = 0;
        
        while(start<=end){
            if (abs(nums[start])<abs(nums[end])){
                sqr = nums[end]*nums[end];
                final[finalIdx] = sqr;
                finalIdx--;
                end--;
            }
            if (abs(nums[start])>abs(nums[end])){
                sqr = nums[start]*nums[start];
                final[finalIdx] = sqr;
                finalIdx--;
                start++;
            }
            else if(abs(nums[start])==abs(nums[end])){
                sqr = nums[end]*nums[end];
                final[finalIdx] = sqr;
                finalIdx--;
                final[finalIdx] = sqr;
                finalIdx--;
                start++;
                end--;
            }
        return final;
        }

    }
};
```

The issue lies in my loop condition I believe. When I change the condition to start<end, I have no compile error, but the first element of the output array (final) is always 0, which I assume is by default. However, when I try to do start<=end in order to add a condition that handles the start==end case, I get the above error. I would like to understand why this is happening so I can rectify the issue. Thanks!

Comment: It is possible to decrement `finalIdx` twice each time round the loop.

Comment: That `return final;` is in the wrong location. It should be after the closing `}` of the while-loop. As shown your code presented will return a vector of at-most 3 entries. Fixing that, you can also make this MUCH simpler by only moving out one slot per iteration. You're literally saving *nothing* by trying to do multiple steps per iteration.

Comment: What would be the intuition behind that? I only decrement that when I am done selecting the squared number and putting it in the `final` array

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig! Don't know how I overlooked that. I changed it but still have the same error

Comment: There are 2 separate `if` tests and an `else if`.  The 1st `if` test (if true) modifies `end--;` and as the 2nd `if` test is not related to the first (it tests different values as `end` was modified), both `if` test could be true and therefore `finalIdx` could be modified twice in the loop.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, thanks! @RichardCritten

Answer (score 0):

First, that's not a "compile error" ; it's a runtime error (and the error message reported says as much.

That said, the issue stems from the condition of `start <= end` landing on the `=` part of that condition. Eventually that is guaranteed to happen, save for one very specific set of circumstances:

- start = (end-1)
- abs(num[start]) == abs(num[end])

When that happens, your code will dump two values to the output vector, and both increment `start` and decrement `end`. The `start` and `end` indexes effectively swap values, the while condition is no longer true, and the loop will now cleanly exit.

In *all* other circumstances `start` and `end` will eventually land on the same index. When that happens your dual-push logic will dump the same value *twice* into the target vector, and that is where the issue manifests. There is only *one* value left to push (and `start` and `end` both reference it by index). Therefore you're going to push one more value into your target vector than you have space for, and the runtime exception ensues.

The fix is simple. Stop trying to be smart about short circuiting in three different conditions when in reality you only need *one* and a master-else. The computational requirements are the same no matter what, and in the end all you need is this:

```
class Solution
{
public:
    std::vector<int> sortedSquares(std::vector<int> const &nums)
    {
        std::vector<int> final(nums.size());
        int start = 0;
        int end = nums.size()-1;
        int finalIdx = final.size()-1;
        
        while(start<=end)
        {
            if (abs(nums[end]) < abs(nums[start]))
            {
                final[finalIdx--] = nums[start]*nums[start];
                ++start;
            }
            else
            {
                final[finalIdx--] = nums[end]*nums[end];
                --end;
            }
        }
        return final;
    }
};
```

If you *really* want all three conditions in your code, it is possible, but not warranted, and the special case circumstances don't justify doing it. Regardless, see below:

```
class Solution
{
public:
    std::vector<int> sortedSquares(std::vector<int> const &nums)
    {
        std::vector<int> final(nums.size());
        int start = 0;
        int end = nums.size() - 1;
        int finalIdx = final.size() - 1;

        while (start <= end)
        {
            if (abs(nums[start]) < abs(nums[end]))
            {
                final[finalIdx--] = nums[end] * nums[end];
                end--;
            }
            else if (abs(nums[end]) < abs(nums[start]))
            {
                final[finalIdx--] = nums[start] * nums[start];
                start++;
            }
            else // !(a<b || b<0) implies (a == b)
            {
                int sqr = final[finalIdx--] = nums[end] * nums[end];
                if (end != start)
                {
                    final[finalIdx--] = sqr;
                }
                --end;
                ++start;
            }
        }
        return final;
    }
};
```

Comment: if finalIdx is set to size-1, won't the first iteration add an element to the 2nd to last slot of the array?

Additionally, I still can't seem to understand why in the case with 2 conditions, does the equal case work when you end--

Comment: @RS The problem with the original algorithm is *exactly* as I described it above. Run the code in a debugger and you will see it for yourself.